# php_curl is enabled but not loaded in php.ini in wampserver windows 8 64bit

Tags: php, windows, curl, wampserver

I have enabled php_curl  on wampserver 2.2 in windows  8  64 bit  but whene i see in php.ini is not loaded so please any idea about this issus to fixe it  ?

Comment: Did the extension has the `;` in front of it or not in .ini? just uncomment, save and restart the server?

Comment: i did all this but no result

Comment: So, you can't really use `curl_init()` ? does `function_exists("curl_init");`? what the error reporting says? `ini_set("display_errors",1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` in top?

Comment: i have delete wampserver and reinstall it again ,so it's solved , i think the labrary was endamged, thanks vlzvl for your sugestion :)

Comment: no prob, either case you solved it :)